# check if large number of directories exist in Python

Tags: python, performance

Is there a trick to quickly check whether 10000 Windows directories exist in Python? I currently stored them in a list, I wonder how to do the check quickly.

Comment: You have a list of paths of directories and you'd like to check, what directories exist in you system and what not, right?
What did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried os.path.exists(), but I wonder if others can have faster methods to solve the problem.

Comment: I would recommend adding a small snippet for that - it is good practice on StackOverflow to show what you've tried so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with multi-process

```
os.access("/file/path/foo.txt", os.F_OK)

# check file is exists
os.F_OK
# check file is readable
os.R_OK
# check file is wirteable
os.W_OK
# check file is execute
os.X_OK
```

It is a simple test

```
In [1]: import os, pathlib

In [2]: p = "/home/lpc/gitlab/config/test"

In [3]: %timeit pathlib.Path(p).exists()
5.85 µs ± 32.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit os.path.exists(p)
1.03 µs ± 4.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit os.access(p, os.F_OK)
526 ns ± 2.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [6]: def check(p):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         f = open(p)
    ...:         f.close
    ...:         return True
    ...:     except:
    ...:         pass

In [7]: %timeit check(p)
1.52 µs ± 4.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit os.path.isdir(p)
1.05 µs ± 4.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I think this is not fast. there are better ways to check if a file exists without open and close each file...

Comment: os.path.exists() is indeed a bit faster than pathlib.

Comment: os.access is faster

Comment: Nice comparison, could you please add `os.path.isdir()` into the mix since the question specifically asks about the existence of directories?

Comment: Thanks for adding it :-) - linking to your answer in mine since it covers a very different aspect (comparing the performance of different methods).

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the list and call `os.path.exists()` (for files and directories), `os.path.isfile()` (for files) or `os.path.isdir()` for directories in order to know whether or not these directories exist:

```
dir_list = [...]
for dir_entry in dir_list:
    if not os.path.isdir(dir_entry):
        # do something if the dir does not exist
    else:
        # do something if the dir exists
```

If you want to just check the existence of the path without checking whether or not it actually is a directory, then there are additional options that may be faster, [see Johnny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526616/1331407) for details.

If simply iterating through the list is not fast enough, you can use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in order to iterate over the list in parallel threads (assign chunks of that list (e.g. 1000 directories) to each worker) but I doubt that that would speed up much and handling the return values (if needed) would be complicated.

```
WORKER_COUNT=10
CHUNK_SIZE=1000
def process_dir_list(dir_list):
    # implementation according to the snippet above
    (...)

future_list = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=WORKER_COUNT) as executor:
    for dir_index in range(0, len(dir_list), CHUNK_SIZE):
        future_list.append(executor.submit(process_dir_list, dir_list[dir_index:dir_index + 1000]))
    # wait for all futures to finish
    for current_future in future_list:
        # wait for the current future to finish
        result = future.result(timeout=0)
        # do something with the result, if desired
```

Comment: Added an example for parallel processing in a ThreadPoolExecutor as well

Comment: if I want the chunking to be flexible, so that I do not need to chunk exactly 1000 each time, is it that I simply do ```[executor.submit(process_dir_list, dir_list) for path in dir_list]```

Comment: not quite, that would just let it iterate over all directories multiple times - I will adjust my code example to be configurable.

Comment: There was an error anyways in `range()` - the 1000 was supposed to be the step size there. It should now be correct. You can also adust the contents of the two variables `WORKER_COUNT` and `CHUNK_SIZE` to your needs (you can have less workers than your `dir_list` divided by `CHUNK_SIZE` - a worker that is finished would just start the next task when ready).

Comment: is there a way to let the last list valid if it has less than 1000 items? numpy.split?

Comment: The way Python works already ensures that slices can get generated even if their limit is higher than the length of the list

Comment: yeah, it's the way that I always do chunking, if required ^^